# Kubuntu 16.04, icon settings / select editor for desktop icon

Tags: kubuntu, icons

In old Kubuntu 12.04 I was able to create a desktop icon for a text file that would open the file in 'nedit' when clicking the icon.

In Kubuntu 16.04 I managed to create the icon (by dragging the file from a file browser to the desktop) but I'm not able to configure that the file should be opened using 'nedit' (instead it is opened in Kate).

When opening the 'icon settings', the only thing I can configure is a keyboard shortcut. I'm missing the configuration of the application used to open the file, which was there (among many more icon settings) in 12.04.

Can anyone suggest a strategy ?

Answer (score 1):

Icon widget properties are back with the Plasma 5.9 or later. Plasma 5.9 beta announcement: https://www.kde.org/announcements/plasma-5.8.95.php :

> The icon widget that is created for you when you drag an application
>   or document onto your desktop or a panel sees the return of a settings
>   dialog: you can now change the icon, label text, working directory,
>   and other properties. Its context menu now also sports an 'Open with'
>   section as well as a link to open the folder the file it points to is
>   located in.

Comment: That's good news. Kde Plasma 5.8 is so crap.